# Is there a way to indicate that a web page may have “disturbing” content for OpenGraph/Google etc

Tags: seo, search-engines, schema.org, meta-tags, open-graph-protocol

I am working on a website that hosts medical imagery. Some of those images might be considered "explicit" or "disturbing", e.g. surgery or diseases.

We would like to add metadata to those web pages to indicate to social media and search engines that these are images are potentially disturbing. Is there a standard way of doing this?

Note that this is not the same as flagging the images as "not safe for work" or even "adult".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### [**Schema.org**](https://schema.org/)

This vocabulary doesn’t seem to offer a suitable way. Nearby are:

- [`isFamilyFriendly`](http://schema.org/isFamilyFriendly)

  > Indicates whether this content is family friendly.
- [`typicalAgeRange`](http://schema.org/typicalAgeRange)

  > The typical expected age range, e.g. '7-9', '11-'.
- And instead of marking for whom it isn’t intended, you could explicitly specify for whom it’s intended, but this doesn’t convey that it’s not also suitable for others: [`audience`](http://schema.org/audience)

  > An intended audience, i.e. a group for whom something was created.

#### [**Open Graph Protocol**](http://ogp.me/)

This vocabulary doesn’t seem to offer a suitable way nor even similar/related properties.

#### Other vocabularies

There are so [many vocabularies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12098901/1591669) that it’s likely that something suitable exists, and if not, you could [create a new vocabulary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21162395/1591669).

But these vocabularies don’t get recognized by the big search engines (they primarily support Schema.org, and in a few cases other popular vocabularies like OGP). This might change if they see widespread use, of course.

---

I think [**POWDER**](https://www.w3.org/TR/powder-primer/), which is [superseding PICS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16449786/1591669) and also standardized by the W3C, could be of interest:

> POWDER — the Protocol for Web Description Resources — provides a mechanism to describe and discover Web resources and helps the users to make a decision whether a given resource is of interest. There are a variety of use cases: from providing a better means to describing Web resources and creating trustmarks to aiding content discovery, child protection and Semantic Web searches.